# Как подключить пакет idna (golang_org/x/net/idna)

Tags: сеть, golang, импорт, package

Здравствуйте!
[Нужны функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/691848/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-punycode-%D0%B2-unicode-golang) для перевода кодировки строки url из пакета **idna** 
**idna.ToASCII** и **idna.ToUnicode**

[Ссылка](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/idna#Profile.ToUnicode) на документацию:
https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/idna#Profile.ToUnicode

Пытаюсь подключить:

```
import "golang_org/x/net/idna"
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
main.go:18:8: cannot find package "golang_org/x/net/idna" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang_org/x/net/idna (from $GOROOT)
    /home/arseny/go/src/golang_org/x/net/idna (from $GOPATH)
```

По другому с указанием полного пути:

```
import "vendor/golang_org/x/net/idna"
```

Другая ошибка:

```
main.go:18:8: must be imported as golang_org/x/net/idna

main.go:19:2: use of vendored package not allowed
```

Самое интересное, эти функции используется в обычной библиотеке **net/http**  пакет request например, но так как они приватные, я не могу их использовать, как быть?

Пример:

```
import(
    "golang_org/x/net/idna"
    "golang_org/x/text/unicode/norm"
    "golang_org/x/text/width"
)

func idnaASCII(v string) (string, error) {
    if isASCII(v) {
        return v, nil
    }
    // The idna package doesn't do everything from
    // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5895 so we do it here.
    // TODO(bradfitz): should the idna package do this instead?
    v = strings.ToLower(v)
    v = width.Fold.String(v)
    v = norm.NFC.String(v)
    return idna.ToASCII(v)
}
```

Comment: `golang.org` же. Напишите так и не забывайте про go get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете использовать внутренние пакеты.

Вам необходимо выполнить команду, чтобы установить его локально.

```
go get golang.org/x/net/idna
```

**Не забудьте только настроить переменную среды** `%GOPATH`.

После этого вы сможете его спокойно импортировать в проект:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/idna"
)

var p *idna.Profile

func main() {
    // Raw Punycode has no restrictions and does no mappings.
    p = idna.New()
    fmt.Println(p.ToUnicode("xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai"))
}
```

Выведет

> президент.рф

Как настроить переменную среды вы можете посмотреть в статье:
"[Быстрый старт – программируем на Go под Windows — настройка Environment](https://habrahabr.ru/post/133281/)"

Comment: Решение конечно помогло, но оно по сути создает копию пакета. Т.е. мне в будущем самостоятельно надо мониторить зависимости и прочее?
Почти аналогично сейчас сделал тоже самое руками. (создал копию пакета и поместил по адресу проекта).

Comment: @Arseny, здесь я точно сказать не могу. Однако где по другому? При использовании Bower или Composer разве вы не мониторите версии самостоятельно? И разве в них не вы определяете набор пакетов, требуемый для проекта?

Comment: Ну смотрите, допустим в 1.9. выходит новая версия этого пакета с доделанными #TODO которые есть в этих пакетах. Мне опять придется ручками делать go get.  Если бы это была нормально подключаемая либа то go по-идее, изначально уже брал нужную либу. Выходит папка vendor - это какие возможно экспериментальные пакеты, поэтому напрямую их подключить без таких вот трюков нельзя.

Comment: @Arseny, теперь я точно понял, о чем вы говорите. Однако в случае с теми же Bower и Composer ситуация абсолютно такая же. Вот есть сейчас Bootstrap v4 alpha 6 с сеткой на флексах по умолчанию. И вроде бы можно его использовать, но следить-то все равно приходится самому, когда там очередная альфа, бета или релиз кандидат выйдет. К сожалению альтернатив я не знаю, да и с этой ситуацией разбирался с 0, чтобы вам помочь.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за помощь.