# Как преобразовать punycode в Unicode?

Tags: http, golang, url, unicode, package

Подскажите какой пакет/либу/функцию использовать для преобразования url строки из punicode в unicode.

Т.е. задача:
xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai ----> kremlin.ru

И наоборот.

Пытался найти [решение](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/idna#example-New), [не могу подключить пакет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/691785/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82-idna-golang-org-x-net-idna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутренние пакеты нельзя подключать.
Его следует установить сначала. Для этого выполните в консоли команду:

```
go get golang.org/x/net/idna
```

После этого его можно использовать.

Comment: Нет ли альтернативы, насколько я понимаю, этой командой мы лишь создаем локальную копию пакета в $GOROOT

Comment: @Arseny, я не совсем понял, почему это может быть проблемой?